# How to obtain tuple values from inside of decorator functions in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am exploring decorator functions in Python. My objective is to return a tuple from a wrapper function inside of the decorator function, when the original function that is passed to the decorator functin also returns a tuple. My code snippet is pasted below:

```
def decorator_function(original_function):

    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        s, o = original_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return s, o

    return wrapper_function


def test_function(name, command):
    status = True
    output = dict()
    output['message'] = command + " " + name
    return status, output


decorator_func_var = decorator_function(test_function("Kaushik", "Hello"))
ok, out = decorator_func_var()
print(ok)
print(out)
```

However, when I execute this, I get an error message as follows:

[image: Error Message]

I am curious to know where I am going wrong with my code snippet and how can I obtain the tuple values when calling a decorated function. I would really appreciate any suggestions or feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decorator takes a function as an argument, and returns a function.  You just want

```
ok, out = decorator_function(test_function)("Kaushik", "Hello")
```

or a little bit more clearly:

```
wrapped_function = decorator_function(test_function)
ok, out = wrapped_function("Kaushik", "Hello")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
def decorator_function(original_function):

    def wrapper_function(*args, **kwargs):
        s, o = original_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return s, o

    return wrapper_function


def test_function(name, command):
    status = True
    output = dict()
    output['message'] = command + " " + name
    return status, output


decorator_func_var = decorator_function(test_function)
ok, out = decorator_func_var("Kaushik", "Hello")
print(ok)
print(out)
```

You pass the parameters after initialising `decorator_func_var`

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Appreciate your feedback.